# Error entries in debug.log

Tags: wp-config, debug

I have enabled error logging in wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
}
```

and I see that debug.log writes a lot of empty lines with only the date

```
[17-Jun-2023 07:24:01 UTC]
[17-Jun-2023 07:24:03 UTC]
[17-Jun-2023 07:24:22 UTC]
```

How can I make it so that lines in which there are no errors are not written to the file ?

Comment: I expect you've got an error_log() call somewhere that's logging an empty string or variable. I don't know of an easy way to track that down sorry, or hook the PHP error_log() calls to add a stack trace, etc. As well as grepping your code, you could try turning off plugins to see if it goes away or switching themes, to help narrow down the search.